# My Conda Starter Guide not functioning as documented

Tags: anaconda, conda, command-prompt

I've just successfully installed Anaconda Python 3.7 on Windows 10 64-bit.
I was directed to the starter guide:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/
and the very first issue presented was to appreciate using the Conda Navigator (GUI) or the Conda prompt. So as instructed, I launched the Conda prompt and got a different prompt:
[image]

I typed:
print("hello!")

followed by ENTER and got the message: Unable to initalize device PRN
I apologize for my inabilityto format my post properly -- where can I learn these basics for Stackoverflow's website?  Would appreciate any assistance in this regard.

Comment: You have to first start, `python` interpreter. Use the command **python** and then you can  try your code.